# jquery DOM manipulation very slow in IE8 especially addClass and removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, addition

I am facing a very strange issue. I have tabs and subtabs in my html and when i click on a tab/subtab 'activeContent' class is placed on it. if i click on another tab/subtab the 'activeContent' class is removed from the previous tab/subtab and placed on the current one. While this scenario works fine when i keep clicking on multiple tabs/subtabs. But in IE8 its very slow. Especially when i hit the back button, the content from the previous subtab is loaded but the active subtab takes a lot of time to change its class. The effect of it is that while that while the content if of some other tab while the active subtab is still the previuos one.

I have even tried to first change the tab/subtab class, something like

```
$(currentTab.node).removeClass('activeContent');
$(tab.node).addClass('activeContent');
```

and then used a seTimeout , something like after the above code gets executed.

```
setTimeout(fuunction(){

//load ajax content
}, 800);
```

Even then the tabs/subtabs takes a lot of time to change its class.

Is this a IE8 or i might i have to optimize my code. I am not sure. Everything works fine in all other browsers including IE6. Is it has something to do with the back button in IE8?

Comment: You better optimize that code because there is no way that adding/removing classes via jQuery is slow in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling this code when you hit the back button? Most likely the back button is causing a page refresh, and you are waiting for the whole page to reload. IE8 is probably just making this behavior more obvious, because it is handing the caching of page content a little differently.

Comment: Yes I am calling this code when i hit the back button. The tabs/ subtabs content is loaded through Ajax. So when I hit the back button, page is not refreshed, rather i change the state of the page depending on the hash. This is rather strange because I am using the same code when i click on tabs and subtabs , while i see slight delay in changing the class but its not very obvious but when i hit the back/forward, i examine the hash and run the same code to switch the tabs and subtab classes that i use on click, and then depending on the url load the ajax content

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative solution for you. Is this a click event on an anchor tag? I have noticed that it takes an exorbitant amount of time for IE to cancel the default action on an anchor tag that has a href property. Especially in IE8.

Here is an example function from my site:

```
function SwapLinks() { // This allows our pages to degrade gracefully. But hrefs are slow. So, if JS is enabled remove the href!
$(".playerLink").each(function (index) {
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    if (link != undefined && link != null && link != "") {
        $(this).removeAttr("href");
        $(this).attr("link", ""); // This little number makes IE6/IE7 happy.
        $(this).attr("link", link);

    }
});
```

Then you would add a click event on (".playerLink") that handles the Ajax updating.

Comment: *"...it takes an exorbitant amount of time for IE to cancel the default action"* - Can you prove it?

Comment: When i test the same thing on our qa server, it works fine..But on my local machine and our dev machine, IE8 is behaving very strange..I am just confused

Comment: @galambalazs. Yes. I can. But I am not going to revert my code back to the slow version just to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with my code actually. I tested on a friends machine and it was working fine. Then i reset IE8 and everything started to work fine. I am not sure why IE8 was behaving in that way. It happened earlier also, I had to reset IE8 because it was not recognizing the app running on jboss server on my local machine by doing this http://my-pc:8080/myapp/mypage.html BUT rather i had to do http://167.232.23.12/myapp/mypage.html and then it would display evrything.  So when i reset the browser , i could run my app through
 http://my-pc:8080/ .

Comment: What do you mean by "reset" IE8? Close & reopen it? Clear caches? As the *Accepted Answer* this would be more useful if you described what you did a bit better.

Comment: Actually I take my answer back, because the problem is still there if the browser mode: IE8 and document mode: IE8 but not if browser mode IE8 document mode IE7. I will be posting the url to show the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it turned out it was because I was forgetting to `return false;` from the `click()` event. (I imagine `e.preventDefault()` would work, too.)

I'd been using a link like `<a href="#">` for my tabs since it doesn't really navigate anywhere, but IE seem to be "trying" to navigate and taking time to do so, so returning false prevents the navigation for real. (And is probably a best practice, and let's me put in "real" links to fall back to which is probably also a best practice.)

It seems especially a problem when I've loaded the page with a `file://` URL on my development machine (as opposed to deploying it to a server and accessing it in the regular way via HTTP).

(Thanks to Jeff Davis and kd44 whose answers above put me on the right track.)